# Close dialog does not open after (inline) editing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, close-dialog

After editing a question inline, clicking on the "close" link does not open the close dialog, the page just scrolls to the top.

Browser (all OS X 10.8.4): Firefox 22.0, Chrome 27.0.1453.116

Comment: Repro'd on the same Chrome version on Windows 7. Bugtastic! Clicking close appends a fragment to the end of the URL... refreshing removes again.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 24 on Ubuntu 13.04. Was about to post one of my own.