# Close popup doesn't appear after editing the question without refreshing the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, vote-to-close, popups

Seems like a bug:

The user:

1. Edits a question
2. Then, he decide to close it.
3. Clicks on the `Close` button.
4. The popup doesn't appear.
5. Refreshes the page.
6. Click on the close button.
7. The popup appears.

After editing in the link appears a hash: `#`. But I don't think that this is the problem because if I add the hash without editing the close popup appears.

It's minor, but I think that is good to be reported and solved.

**Edit:** The close popup doesn't open after we click ***an edit has been made to this post; click to load***.

Comment: Reproduced even if someone else edits it.

Comment: The close popup doesn't open after we click `an edit has been made to this post; click to load`

Comment: The `Flag` dialog is also not opening. (Same as close dialog).

Comment: Reproduced with me as well. Even i too was going to post a bug.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185886/142802.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had some JS issues here - inline editing replaces those links completely, killing some attached event handlers.

Fixed in the next build.