# Flag dialog doesn't appear after editing the question

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, flags

Related to this [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186246/205508):

Flag dialog doesn't appear after the question is edited:

- by the user which edit the question and then decides to flag it
- by the other users, after clicking ***"an edit has been made to this post; click to load"***

After refreshing the page, it appears (when it's clicked).

Comment: I don't think we need separate bug report for this. Same core problem, so fix will solve both reports. Just mention it applies to flag dialog as well in the first report.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, but I think that it's more organized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had some JS issues here - inline editing replaces those links completely, killing some attached event handlers.

Fixed in the next build.