# "You may only load the flag dialog every 3 seconds" shows up on every click, but the dialog still opens

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, error-message

When [reviewing flags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) in the 10k tools, every click of the **flag or disagree** button brings up this popup, but the dialog still shows normally on top of it. It's nothing more than an annoyance, but still, a bug is a bug.

> [image: Weird popup behind]

The same thing happens when clicking the **close question** button.

Comment: The dialog actually attempts to open twice because there are two delegated event handlers (and the handler doesn't cancel the event), possibly related to the [fix for it not working after an inline edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186246/close-popup-doesnt-appear-after-editing-the-question-without-refreshing-the-pag).

Comment: @animuson Thanks, awesome edit:)

Comment: @TimStone Nice find, thanks:)