# EEEEK! I can't close anything!

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

Normal users can post close votes, but my binding vote won't work.  Confirmed by several members in the Teacher's Lounge.

[image]

Comment: Just cast the 5th close vote on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17331653), so this seems to be limited to the binding vote.

Comment: This is actually likely a symptom of [the duplicate dialog issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186391/you-may-only-load-the-flag-dialog-every-3-seconds-shows-up-on-every-click-but), just that it ends up being weirder because I guess moderators [are immune to the dialog rate limiting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nNWVB.png), and actually get both dialogs.

Comment: As a normal user (on SO), I had to try 2 or 3 times to cast a vote on the question that triggered this.

Comment: By the way, I got the “you may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds” popup, partly hidden behind the close dialog.

Comment: I also just found I couldn't click on a duplicate to select it, not sure if related.

Comment: Upvoted for animated hilarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've backed out the offending changesets and will be building shortly.

The responsible party will be chastened.

Comment: Will that require a mirror? :)

Comment: Hehe, no, other than I didn't test the other person's code.  I'll let him out himself :)

Comment: It is his fault --->

Answer (score 16):

Yeah, as I suspected, this appears to be linked to the [duplicate dialog bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186391/you-may-only-load-the-flag-dialog-every-3-seconds-shows-up-on-every-click-but). You can work around it using developer tools for the moment, by running the following snippet before clicking the close link:

```
$('#mainbar').data('events').click.pop()
```

This will unbind one of the duplicate event handlers so that you'll only get a single dialog, and everything [appears to work okay](https://stackapps.com/posts/4184/revisions) from there on out.

Comment: Why hasn't SE hired you yet?

Comment: I'm not the most qualified candidate, or something. :)

Comment: Do I need Firebug to run that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey if your in firefox then yes. in chrome you just right click and say inspect element. Then you can click on the console button. where you can run this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You should be able to run it with the `javascript:` protocol in the URL bar, but I think Firefox has a console built-in if you Ctrl+Shift+K now (not as nice as Firebug, but it will work for this purpose)

Comment: @TimStone I didn't think Firefox allows `javascript:` calls..

Comment: I ran it in Chrome's console.  It worked.

Comment: @Seth Ah, you're right, it doesn't even if you type it in manually. Never mind that, then.

Comment: BTW, which duplicate dialog bug are we talking about?

Comment: @Seth Oh, I had linked to it in the comments on the question but not in the answer...whoops, fixed. For convenience: ["You may only load the flag dialog every 3 seconds" shows up on every click, but the dialog still opens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186391)

Comment: Woohoo, this workaround also let me migrate a question!